# Determining Document Library to Upload Files PowerShell Script

Tags: document-library, powershell

I have a network folder that contains 50 documents. I need to upload the files to the specified SharePoint document library based on a csv filename and document library.

CSV Example:

filename1  doclibA

filename2    doclibB

filename3    doclibA

filename4    doclbC

Any scripts on uploading multiple documents from a folder to a SharePoint document library based on a CSV list of the filename and the document library it should go to, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your query, you can write your custom application to upload the files to sharepoint documnet library. In that applicayion you can check the extension of the file and upload file to that document library.

Use can use server object model or client object model to upload files to sharepoint document library.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint